# Unable to pass data to web method always getting null c#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, web-services

I am unable to send data from my client app to a web method, i dont actually know what i am doing wrong any help would be appreciate.

Client:

```
    public void syncClient(Customer c) 
    {
        try
        {
                var datos = new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(c);
                DataContractJsonSerializer ser =
                new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(string));
                MemoryStream mem = new MemoryStream();
                ser.WriteObject(mem, datos);

                string data = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(mem.ToArray(), 0, (int)mem.Length);

                string url = store.ParentUrl + "Api/syncClientFromChild";

                HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
                request.ContentType = @"application/json"; //set the content type to JSON
                request.Method = "POST";

                System.Text.UTF8Encoding encoding = new System.Text.UTF8Encoding();

                byte[] send = encoding.GetBytes(data);
                request.ContentLength = send.Length;

                using (Stream newStream = request.GetRequestStream())
                {
                    newStream.Write(send, 0, send.Length);
                }

                WebResponse ws1 = request.GetResponse();
                JavaScriptSerializer serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
                ApiCtrlResponse response = serializer.Deserialize<ApiCtrlResponse>(serializer.Serialize(ws1.GetResponseStream()));
                if (response.success == true)
                {
                    c.Synced = true;
                    _customerService.UpdateCustomer(c);
                }

        }
        catch (Exception A)
        {
        }
    }
```

I believe thats fine, but the other method i always get null in the string i need to receive:

```
[System.Web.Services.WebMethod]
public ActionResult syncClientFromChild(string Customer)
{
    // do something
}
```

What i am missing ? Thanks in advance !

Comment: Have you checked whether `data` contains the right serialized data?

Answer (score 0):

use a Model to accept  Http Post,try to not use string,like

```
public class ReceiveModel
{
string Customer;
}

public ActionResult syncClientFromChild(ReceiveModel model)
```